# Laravel chunk and delete

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jobs

I have a large number of items (1M+) that i want to delete from a database, i fork a background job to take care of that, so that the user won't have to wait for it to finish to carry on whatever he/she was doing, the problem is, the app becomes unresponsive while the items are being deleted, so i thought that i would process the items chunk by chunk and sleep for a couple of seconds then carry on.

Here is the code that handles the delete:

```
// laravel job class
// ...
public function handle()
{
    $posts_archive = PostArchive::find(1); // just for the purpose of testing ;)
    Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->chunk(1000, function ($posts) {
        //go through the collection and delete every post.
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            $post->delete();
        }
        // throttle
        sleep(2);
    });
}
```

**Expected result**: the posts are chunked and each chunk is processed, then idle for 2 seconds, repeat that until all the items are deleted.

**Actual result**: a random number of items is deleted once, then the process ends. no errors no indicators, no clue ?

is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: I don't understand why did you do this way. It's faster if you run a delete command at once, instead of running 1000 commands.

Comment: Yeah, you don't typically need to chunk a deletion, unless you're looking to do some sort of additional processing on each item as you do so.

Comment: deleting a large number of items in one single operation makes the Ui unresponsive.

Comment: Deleting them in chunks will take just as long (longer!), and the `sleep(2)` every thousand of a million items is going to mean the UI is unresponsive for ~30 minutes *literally doing nothing* on top of that.

Comment: actually the `sleep(2)` is sort of not doing anything which means other processes can use the CPU, and the Ui is unresponsive because the database engine is busy processing a large number of items in one operation, so if you want to access another part of the app which uses the database then that part of the app stops responding.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to call delete on each model?

Comment: i can't call delete on the collection can i?

Comment: Sure you can. `Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->delete()`.

Comment: No, you'd use the delete method on the query, not the collection

Comment: i hope that my question is clear, the problem here is not the running time of the job itself, it's about optimizing the deletion of 1M+ items on the database, that operation is time consuming, so i though i would throttle that, deleting only a bunch of records at a time, then sleeping in between.

Comment: The way you're currently doing it does a `SELECT *`, fetching the full contents, then individually runs a `DELETE FROM table WHERE id=123` on every row. You're issuing at least a million (plus another thousand or so) queries to do what a single `Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->delete()` (`DELETE FROM foo WHERE arch_id=bar`) would suffice.

Comment: Your "optimization" would increase load substantially by calling 1,000,000 queries instead of 1 but spread it out over a very long period of time.  I wouldn't really call that optimizing.

Comment: @ceejayoz well actually that was the first thing i did, the problem is that it takes a while to finish which makes the app unresponsive.

Comment: for the record i already used `Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->delete()`, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: i've looked for a way to optimize deletion for large number of records, but didn't find something for laravel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing Laravel specific about the way you'd handle this.  It sounds like your database server needs review or optimization if a delete query in a job is freezing the rest of the UI.

Retrieving each model and running a delete query individually definitely isn't a good way to optimize this as you'd be executing millions of queries.  You could use a while loop with a delete limit if you wish to try to limit the load per second in your application instead of optimizing your database server to handle this query:

```
do {
    $deleted = Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->limit(1000)->delete();
    sleep(2);
} while ($deleted > 0);
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for. maybe i'll have to optimize that database server to handle these kind of queries. thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The reason your actual outcome is different to the expected outcome is to do with how Laravel chunks your dataset.

Laravel *paginates* through your dataset 1-page at a time, and passes the Collection of `Post` models to your callback.

Since you're deleting the records in the set, Laravel effectively skips a page of data on each iteration, therefore you end up missing roughly half the data that was in the original query.

Take the following scenario – there are **24 records** that you wish to delete in **chunks of 10**:

**Expected**

```
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
|  Iteration  |   Eloquent query   | Rows returned to callback |
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
| Iteration 1 | OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10  |                        10 |
| Iteration 2 | OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 |                        10 |
| Iteration 3 | OFFSET 20 LIMIT 10 |                         4 |
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
```

**Actual**

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
|  Iteration  |   Eloquent query   | Rows returned to callback  |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| Iteration 1 | OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10  |                         10 | (« but these are deleted)
| Iteration 2 | OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 |                          4 |
| Iteration 3 | NONE               |                       NONE |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

After the 1st iteration, there were only 14 records left, so when Laravel fetched page 2, it only found 4 records.

The result, is that 14 records out of 24 were deleted, and this feels a bit random but makes sense in terms of how Laravel processes the data.

Another solution to the problem would be to [use a cursor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#chunking-results) to process your query, this will step through your DB result-set 1 record at a time, which is better use of memory.

E.g.

```
// laravel job class
// ...
public function handle()
{
    $posts_archive = PostArchive::find(1); // just for the purpose of testing ;)
    $query = Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id);

    foreach ($query->cursor() as $post) {
        $post->delete();
    }
}
```

NB: The other solutions here are better if you only want to delete the records in the DB. If you have any other processing that needs to occur, then using a cursor would be a better option.

Comment: that is a great explanation for how chunk works :) ,well  i wasn't really planning on processing individual records, all i needed to do is delete them in a way that doesn't impact App responsiveness. thanks anyway.

Comment: Any comment on whether `chunkById()` would also solve this problem? https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#chunking-results

Comment: @BlueC yes, that is exactly what `chunkById` is intended for

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I totally forgot about the offset and limit it uses behind the scene altogether.

Answer (score 4):

As Kelvin Jones points out, the reason the random number of items is being deleted is that you're deleting records as you page through them.

`chunk` simply uses offset & limit to "paginate" through your table. But if you delete 100 records from page 1 (IDs 1-100), then go to page 2, you're actually now skipping IDs 101-200 and jumping to 201-300.

`chunkById` is a way around this

```php
Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->chunkById(1000, function ($posts) {
    //go through the collection and delete every post.
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $post->delete();
    }
});
```

Literally just replace the method name. Now, instead of using offset & limit to paginate, it will look at the maximum primary key (100) from the first page, then the next page will query `where ID > 100`. So page 2 is now correctly giving you IDs 101-200 instead of 201-300.

Comment: but what if a new row is added during the process does the max id will still be maintained when the query first ran or will it change to the latest added row?

Comment: @AnujShrestha pretty sure it checks the max ID each time the next "chunk" is fetched, so it will include the new row. You could try it and let me know if that's wrong

Comment: it looks like behind the scene it uses `->where($column, '>', $lastId)
                    ->orderBy($column, 'asc')`. So it will include the new rows formed since it is performing on a loop to check the count.  I had a problem of never-ending artisan command on schedule due to new rows being added while processing using chunk feature. I had to get the last id myself before performing the main sql query

Comment: @AnujShrestha I thought so. I think that all of the Laravel methods, `chunk`, `chunkById`, and `cursor` would have the same issue. You would need to get the max ID first, and then add a `where` filter. It's kind of a different topic from this question though, I think you should post a separate question about it and self-answer with what you discovered, and see if anybody has other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the issue is that deleting a large amount of entries takes too much ressources. 
doing it one post at a time will take too long too.

try getting the min and the max of post.id then chunk on those like

```
for($i = $minId; $i <= $maxId-1000; $i+1000) {
    Post::where('arch_id', $posts_archive->id)->whereBetween('id', [$i, $i+1000])->delete();
    sleep(2);
}
```

customize the chunk and the sleep period as it suites your server ressources.