# MySQL bin log breaking in chunks

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I am trying to delete records from a table like

```
DELETE * FROM table WHERE x=1 LIMIT 200000;
```

When I am checking my bin logs it is showing breaking of this delete statement into further smaller chunks like:

```
sql(0):
  336 records
sql(1):
   336 records
```

This is creating a spike in my replication. Any ideas why bin-log breaking things in smaller chunks? for framework I am using laravel

Comment: `DELETE *` is not a thing

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DELETEs do not chunk, which is why chunking is done manually.

You're using row-based replication; statement-based replication would not incur this problem, although it might have other drawbacks - there's a discussion in the manual about pros and cons of RBR versus SBR.

Unless you're doing your chunking in Laravel [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483342/laravel-chunk-and-delete), there is no reason why you should get that behaviour. What might be happening is that you have very large lines and [very small max_allowed_packet_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-max-allowed-packet.html), so the server is sending the delete messages in chunks to fit them in the packet:

> Row-based replication currently sends **all columns and column values
>   for updated rows from the master to the slave, including values of
>   columns that were not actually changed by the update**. This means that,
>   when you are replicating large column values using row-based
>   replication, you must take care to set `max_allowed_packet` large enough
>   to accommodate the largest row in any table to be replicated, even if
>   you are replicating updates only, or you are inserting only relatively
>   small values.

On the other hand, RBR and deletion on a table (unless it has a primary index) is a bloodbath for replication; been there, done that, watched horrified as the slave went unresponsive. You **want** chunk deletion; probably the chunk size needs to be adjusted or a delay added.

For some methods on how to do so, see [this answer](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).